# Can you integrate Google Nearby API in a flutter app to share wifi credentials?

Tags: flutter

Looking to use Android Things to make an it device and Flutter for a cross platform app. Does anyone know how one would go about using Google Nearby API to communicate between the two to set up a local WiFi network.

Answer (score 2):

> Flutter uses a flexible system that allows you to call
>   platform-specific APIs whether available in Java or Kotlin code on
>   Android, or in ObjectiveC or Swift code on iOS.

You can read more about it here: https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

I guess the android platform specific implementation can be found in the Google Nearby docs.

Comment: So since the Nearby API is provided for both Android and iOS, I would likely have to drop into platform-specific code to use the API?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. You 'only' have to implement the message sending and receiving and can use the platform specific code for the actual implementation.

If you're lucky you can find a package on https://pub.dartlang.org/packages already.

If not - and you develop your code accordingly you might be able to release it as a dart-pub-package